# Cascading dropdown list in SPFx web part

Tags: spfx-webparts, dropdown, react, cascading-dropdown

Can someone help me with this issue as I would like to create cascading dropdown lists inside the web part itself and not in the property pane.

I have found this code in [github [react-custompropertypanecontrols](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-custompropertypanecontrols)" which does exactly what I want but I want them to be displayed in the web part itself.

Any help, please?

Comment: Link in your question is dead.. pls recheck this

Comment: oops. link added

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [SPServices](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/)

`$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
 relationshipList: "States",
 relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",
 relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
 parentColumn: "Country",
 childColumn: "State",
 debug: true
});`

You can check the example in the below link

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37676.sharepoint-2013-cascade-dropdown-list-using-spservices-spservices-spcascadedropdowns.aspx

The below image is very helpful to avoid confusion with using it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A cascading dropdown list in an SPFx web part using PnP JS can be created by following these steps:

- Install the PnP JS library by running the command npm install
  @pnp/pnpjs in the terminal.
- Import the necessary modules from the PnP JS library in your web
  part's component class.
- In the componentDidMount() method, use PnP JS to retrieve the options
  for the first dropdown list from a SharePoint list.
- Bind the options to the state variable of the first dropdown list.
- Create a method to handle the onChange event of the first dropdown
  list. In this method, use PnP JS to retrieve the options for the
  second dropdown list based on the selected option of the first
  dropdown list.
- Bind the options to the state variable of the second dropdown list.
- In the render method, use the state variables to set the selected
  options of the two dropdown lists and to populate the options.
- Use the onChange event of the first dropdown list to trigger the
  method that retrieves the options for the second dropdown list and
  updates the state.

Here is an example of how you might retrieve options for the first dropdown list using PnP JS:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

componentDidMount() {
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ListName").items.select("Title").get().then((items: any[]) => {
        this.setState({
            firstDropdownOptions: items.map(i => ({ key: i.Title, text: i.Title }))
        });
    });
}

handleFirstDropdownChange = (event: any) => {
    const selectedOption = event.target.value;
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ListName").items.filter(`ColumnName eq '${selectedOption}'`).select("Title").get().then((items: any[]) => {
        this.setState({
            secondDropdownOptions: items.map(i => ({ key: i.Title, text: i.Title }))
        });
    });
}
```